# Add Mobile XXM sitemap and "Desktop" sitemap for a site with different HTML on the same URL?

Tags: html, mobile, seo, google-search-console

On my sites, I used the scheme that Google defines: "Dynamically serving different HTML on the same URL" when I offer a mobile version of my code. I have only one URL for each page. By checking the user agent, I decide the version of the site that should appear. I have already a normal XML sitemap of my site and now I want to add a mobile sitemap. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
 xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0">
 <url>
   <loc>http://mobile.example.com/articolo100.html</loc>
<mobile:mobile/>
```

I know that I can add only URLs that provide mobile contents, in my case any URL dynamic serves desktop and mobile needs. I don't want to know if my sites will gain some pagerank with the attribution of a Mobile sitemap. I want to know if is correct to add the mobile sitemap and the "desktop" sitemap in a site of type "Dynamically serving different HTML on the same URL". With this kind of content organization I have to remove all the sitemaps?